# Install content bundle only on author?

Tags: configuration, aem

We have special content bundle that should be present only on author. Is it possible to configure bundle to do that? In maven pom the only difference is slingPort, and I feel that it's not very nice to rely on this parameter.

Part of my pom dm-all, which is responsible for install:

```
<dependencies>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-config</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>content-package</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-view</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>content-package</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-view-author</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>content-package</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-content</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>content-package</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-services</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-osgi-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cqblueprints.taglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cqblueprints-taglib-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- extensions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-osgi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <root>/apps/dm/install</root>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>

                            <embeddedTarget>/apps/dm/install</embeddedTarget>
                            <embeddeds>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dm-services</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </embedded>
                                <!-- extensions -->
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>wink-osgi</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </embedded>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </embedded>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>org.aopalliance</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
                                </embedded>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.inject</artifactId>
                                </embedded>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>geronimo-osgi-registry</artifactId>
                                </embedded>
                                <embedded>
                                    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                                </embedded>
                            </embeddeds>
                            <subPackages>
                                <subPackage>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dm-config</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </subPackage>
                                <subPackage>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dm-view</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </subPackage>
                                <subPackage>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dm-content</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </subPackage>
                                <subPackage>
                                    <groupId>com.cqblueprints.taglib</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cqblueprints-taglib-all</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </subPackage>
                                <subPackage>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dm-view-author</artifactId>
                                    <filter>true</filter>
                                </subPackage>
                            </subPackages>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy-all</id>
            <!--
                when activated, this profile will deploy and install the built CQ package to the target server.
            -->
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>deployPackage</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-package</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Pom of dm-view-author, which I want to nistall on author only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>CQ</artifactId>
        <groupId>EF</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dm-view-author</artifactId>
    <packaging>content-package</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId} - ${project.artifactId}</name>

    <description>
        Content package that deployed only on author instance.
    </description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-content-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/vault-work</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/content</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/.svn</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/.vlt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/.vltignore</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/.DS_Store</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: 1. What does the "content bundle" contain ? 2. How are you deploying your content bundle to the AEM instances (author and/or publish) ? 3. Is "content bundle" a stand alone maven project ?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "content bundle" you mean "content package". Since the author and publish usually share the same codebase no, it's not possible to install a content package only on author. There are ways to make it work only on author, but I need to know more details about your use case.

Comment: Yes, it is content package. It contains a couple of js files that should be installed on author only. Currently it is deployed by content-package-maven-plugin. My idea is to forbid deploy of this package by the means of CQ, since I don't want to rely on maven profiles. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Serge - Is there any issue in moving the "author only" resources (java/jsp/xmls) to a separate content package and have a profile to deploy only to author (with author's target url) ? This will keep the author-only and generic resources separate and modular . What do you think ?

Comment: Yeah, probably, it's the most viable idea :) Thank You, I'll do another profile

Comment: Cool . Moving this from comment to answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving "**author only**" resources (java/jsp/xmls) to a separate content package and have a profile to deploy only to author (with author's target url) ? This will keep the author-only and generic resources separate and modular .